# OpenText Reddot CMS Version Control

Tags: version-control, content-management-system, release-management, reddot

Does anyone know how you version / source control changes in Reddot Cms (OpenText). Also is there any best practice advice for release management of changes from one Reddot environment to another Reddot instance. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is best-practice, but as you have probably realised, there aren't too many practitioners of RedDot these days.  In case you should come back to this thread (or for someone else's benefit) Versioning is built into the Template Manager, but has to be enabled.  There's no Source Control integration last time I checked, but we developed a prototype system that allows for the creation of templates in Visual Studio.  The project to complete that has since died due to lack of commercial support, but some of the ideas may be useful for you if you want it.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for taking the time to reply. I would be very interested in anything that could supply me with that might help with situation. It is very difficult to find anything on Reddot these days and I have inheritted a few reddot sites.

Answer (score 0):

I split up the answer in two parts: Versioning and migration between stages.

Versioning can only be done with the template history or via an external service that grabs the templates on a regular basis or triggered manually. At least for the Management Server there is no built-in service for a "real" versioning or release of more than just single templates/content classes or even including pages.

There are 3 ways of moving changes from dev to test or prod I have seen often:

- Two templates: Using two templates on one server, on called "Development" and the other one "Production". All new development is done on the "Development" template and moved to the other template as soon as finished. If elements are different between those templates they need to be duplicated. This is typically on small installations without staging areas. Nowadays, you will find only very few of those.
- Partial tree export: Development is done on a dev server and the changes are exported as partial tree. There is a special area in the project tree where pages are created which templates shall be moved over. These are exported including the templates and imported on the target server to override the existing ones.
- Tool support: There are external tools for moving templates and content classes to other servers. There is e.g. SitePort (http://siteport.net , can also move whole templates between RedDot servers afaik) and the Sync Tool (http://www.erminas.de/en/products#synctool , can compare and move single element attributes and/or single lines of templates, please note: this shall not be advertisement as the tool is made by us but I do not know any other like this). Some companies also have custom development tools for this.